# My app crashes absolutly everytime it resume active from background on iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

It crashes 100% whenever it go back from background!However,it work fine on iOS9. Is there anything new to iOS10 that our developers must deal with?I am new to iOS10,give me some advice please,thanks in advance.
Before I ask the question I had try:

1. add NSContactsUsageDescription to info.plist
2. check the code in AppDelegate.m's delegate function,nothing abnormal

The console just show "WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO" and the thread shows "EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1,subcode=0*101345c54)".I had check the "zomibe objects"in diagnostics.

Comment: What have you tried? What appears in your stack trace when your app crashes?

Comment: You should at least post related codes & crash logs.

Comment: Better to use fabric and crashlytics for tracing crashes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add in plist

```
 <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) contact use</string>
```

In ios 10 permission changed for contact

Comment: I had tried what you said,but it didn't work for me.

Comment: check background modes in app targets /capabilites try to on that and check once

Comment: I had turn on the background modes,but it crashes too @IOS DEV

Comment: Thanks anyway and with your info I know I must configure my info.plist to fit iOS 10.